# needing help creating a script to find if a folder has been modified in the last day and if not create a txt file in a location

Tags: vbscript, directory, last-modified, days

I'm trying to create a script that finds if a folder hasn't been modified in the last day and create a text file in a location. However if it has been modified in the last day I want it to quit the script.

At the moment, I have only been able to create one (due to my basic knowledge of VBscripting) that finds if a folder exists and if so creates a script.

This however, doesn't work as the subfolder is created daily with a new name and obviously this means my script would have to be changed daily which is pointless.

I need to have the parent folder read and a text file created in another location
if the last modified date isn't < 1 day.

This is the script so far:

```
 Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   If objFSO.FolderExists("c:\test") Then
   wsscript.quit
   Else
   dim filesys, filetxt, getname, path 
   Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
   Set filetxt = filesys.CreateTextFile("c:\test\test.txt", True) 
   path = filesys.GetAbsolutePathName("c:\test\test.txt") 
   getname = filesys.GetFileName(path) 
   filetxt.WriteLine("file doesnt exist.") 
   filetxt.Close 
   End If
```

I know I need to change the .folderExists line to something like

```
if file.DateLastModified > dateadd("h", -24, Now) then
```

I would like a day parameter rather than an hour; I know this means turning the h into a d but I am unsure past that.

it has been solved by Mr Bond! the wonderful man he is. however i now have another question, any idea how to add a command to send an outlook email into this? as the else option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `DateLastModified` property of the `Folder` object.

```
If objFSO.GetFolder("c:\test").DateLastModified >= Date - 1 Then
    ' Folder modified within last day
Else
    ' Folder modified more than a day ago
End
```

There's no need to use `DateAdd()` to add/subtract days. You can just use integer arithmetic.

Note that this will yield a *time* of zero/midnight. So it's really checking to see if the folder was modified since the start of the day yesterday, not in the last 24 hours. That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: would you know how to add a section to send an email after the 'else' option?

Comment: Search this site for `[vbscript] CDO`. There are a lot of great examples for using the _Collaboration Data Objects_ library to send e-mail from VBScript. Good luck.